# Combinatorics generating functions of a series

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Hi I found that the generating function of a series $a_n$ is:

$$\frac{(1-x)(1+2x)}{(1+3x)(1-3x)}$$

I need to find a formula for $a_n$.

I tried some things and found that the generating function is equal to:

$$\frac{1}{3}\cdot (1+2x)\cdot( \frac{2}{1+3x} + \frac{1}{1-3x})$$

but I cant get any further than that.

Comment: it's $(1+x-2x^2)(1+(9x)^2+(9x)^4+...)$

Comment: You need to write the binomial series for the fractions.  Do you know how to expand $(1-9x^2)^{-1}$ in series?

Comment: @saulspatz I think its like $\sum_{n = 0}^{inf} (3x)^{2n}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner and how can I progress from there? I could split it to 2 answers based on if n is even / odd but I think I need to give more explicit answer

Comment: That's right.  Can you see how to multiply that by $(1-x)(1+2x)=(1+x-2x^2)$?

Comment: No, and that's where I'm stuck @saulspatz

Comment: Write $\sum a_nx^n = (1+x-2x^2)\sum 9^nx^{2n}$  Try to work out the first few coefficients, $a_0, a_1, \dots$ and I think you'll see whats going on, and how to write down the formula.  You just have to remember that the coefficient of $x^n$ must be the same on both sides.

Comment: I agree you will get different formulas for $a_n$ depending if $n$ is even or odd

Comment: @saulspatz so I'll get different formulas for $a_n$ depending if n is even or odd?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you will.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach  is fine.  We see or obtain with polynomial division
\begin{align*}
1+2x=\frac{2}{3}(1+3x)+\frac{1}{3}\quad&\Longrightarrow\quad\frac{1+2x}{1+3x}=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3(1+3x)}\\
1+2x=-\frac{2}{3}(1-3x)+\frac{5}{3}\quad&\Longrightarrow\quad\frac{1+2x}{1-3x}=-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{5}{3(1-3x)}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We start with OPs expression and obtain with (1) and the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{1}{3}}&\color{blue}{(1+2x)\left( \frac{2}{1+3x} + \frac{1}{1-3x}\right)}\\
> &=\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1+2x}{1+3x}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1+2x}{1-3x}\\
> &=\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3(1+3x)}\right)+\frac{1}{3}\left(-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{5}{3(1-3x)}\right)\\
> &=\frac{2}{9}+\frac{2}{9}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-3)^nx^n+\frac{5}{9}\sum_{n=0}^\infty 3^nx^n\\
> &\,\color{blue}{=\frac{2}{9}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{9}\left(2(-1)^n+5\right)3^nx^n}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

We start from the generating function:
$$f(x)=\frac{(1-x)(1+2x)}{(1+3x)(1-3x)} = (1-x)\frac{(1+2x)}{(1+3x)(1-3x)} $$
The denominator of the fraction has the zeroes $1/3,-1/3$. Their reciprocals are therefore $3,-3$.

Therefore the explicit formula for $\frac{(1+2x)}{(1+3x)(1-3x)} $  has the form
$$
a_n = \alpha\cdot (3)^n + \beta \cdot(-3)^n
$$

We have 
$$
a_0 = \frac{(1+2x)}{(1+3x)(1-3x)} \bigg|_{x=0}  =1\\
a_1 = \frac d {dx}\frac{(1+2x)}{(1+3x)(1-3x)}  \bigg|_{x=0} = 2$$

And therefore obtain the linear equation system
$$
1 = \alpha + \beta  \\
2 = \alpha\cdot (3) + \beta \cdot(-3)
$$

And with it the explicit formula 
$$\frac{(1+2x)}{(1+3x)(1-3x)} = 
\sum_{n\ge 0}
5/6·3^n + 1/6·(-3)^n x^n
$$

Therefore, we have:
$$
f(x) = 
(1-x)\frac{(1+2x)}{(1+3x)(1-3x)} = (1-x)
\sum_{n\ge 0}
5/6·3^n + 1/6·(-3)^n x^n
\\ =
(\sum_{n\ge 0}
5/6·3^n + 1/6·(-3)^n x^n) - (\sum_{n\ge 0}
5/6·3^n + 1/6·(-3)^n x^{n+1})
\\
=1+\sum_{n\ge 1} (5/6·3^n + 1/6·(-3)^n - (5/6·3^{n - 1} + 1/6·(-3)^{n - 1})) x^n
$$

Comment: Why do all this?  Look at the first comment under the question.

Comment: @saulspatz Why do anything, when wolframAlpha gives the series expansion directly? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+expansion+of+%281+-+x%29%C2%B7%281+%2B+2%C2%B7x%29%2F%28%281+%2B+3%C2%B7x%29%C2%B7%281+-+3%C2%B7x%29%29

Comment: You miss my point; I'm not saying don't do it by hand, but that this seems like an unnecessarily complex method.

Comment: @saulspatz True, it's long and elaborate, but it's also (almost) the standard procedure for translating a rational function into its series expansion (or equivalently calculating the explicit formula for a linear recursion). Can't hurt to have a standard approach that always works in the answers instead of answers exploiting tricks that may or may not work in similar problems.  I'm just still missing a name for the theorem (the huge one relating linear recursions with constant coefficients, rational generating functions and their series expansion) to put on the bottom with a link...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use partial fractions to rewrite as
$$\frac{2}{9}+\frac{2/9}{1-(-3x)}+\frac{5/9}{1-3x}.$$

Comment: I can't understand how you got to this

Comment: @DanielSegal Expand the numerator, and try and write it in the form
$$p(x)(1-9x^2)+A(1-3x)+(1+3x).$$ You get $p(x)$ by a long division. After that the remainder (a polynomial of degree at most one) can be written as a linear combination of the two factors. In other words, it is just like when working out partial fractions when integrating.